# Async action not adding data to Redux store in time leading to, Error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I'm having a issue with an asynchronous action in Redux.

Error: `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined Map: 71`

The issue is that at the time the MapContainer component is attempting to mount before the response of the aysnc `device` action has been added to Redux store yet. So `this.props.device` is undefined and I can't call map on it. But I need to do something to this effect to get the data in MapContainer component.

My initial attempt to resolve this was to move the `this.props.dispatch(setDevice())` from the `componentWillMount()` of the MapContainer component to the `componentWillMount()` of the parent App component.

Basically I need to figure out a way to get `this.props.device` to have its correct data at the time the MapContainer component is mounted, or at least at the time when the interpenetrate is at the `render()` method of the MapContainer component when it attempts to resolve `this.props.device.sessions.map`.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated. Is this the kind of thing people use RxJS observable to resolve? Is there a simple way to fix this without adding new tools?

components/Map.js:

```
            <LayersControl position='topright'>
                {console.log('#########this.props', this.props)}
                {
                    this.props.device.sessions.map((session, i) => {
                        return (
                            <Overlay name={String(i + 1)} key={i}>
                                <Polyline color='red' positions={session.waypoints} />
                            </Overlay>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </LayersControl>
```

components/App.js:

```
componentWillMount() {
    //console.log('this.props', this.props)
    console.log('dispatch setDevice')
    this.props.dispatch(setDevice())
}
```

actions/device.js:

```
export function setDevice(data) {
    console.log('in setDevice action')
    return {
        type: 'SET_DEVICE',
        payload: fetch('/click')
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('in second then of fetch')
                return data
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
}
```

reducers/device.js:

```
export default function reducer(state = {
    device: ''
}, action) {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'SET_DEVICE':
            console.log('in reducer SET_DEVICE case')
            return {...state, data: action.payload, device: action.payload[0] }
        default:
            console.log('in reducer DEFAULT case')
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are using async data, your component should be able to render with empty/null/no data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a condition to check if `this.props.device.session` is not undefined,

```
<LayersControl position='topright'>
                {console.log('#########this.props', this.props)}
                {
                    this.props.device.sessions && this.props.device.sessions.map((session, i) => {
                        return (
                            <Overlay name={String(i + 1)} key={i}>
                                <Polyline color='red' positions={session.waypoints} />
                            </Overlay>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </LayersControl>
```

or You can initialize `data.sessions` as an empty array and overwrite it when data from async action comes back.